# Display none some content and block one element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to make 3 buttons with each one make all the content div to `display: none` and depending on the button you have click one of the content div change to `display: block`. For example, If I click on the second button It will show only the second div content.

```js
function showPanel(id) {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
  }

  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showPanel('1')">test1</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('2')">test2</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('3')">test3</button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="1" class="content">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="content">
    <p class="other">TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="content ">
    <p class="other">TEST3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `elements.length()` is not a function, it is a property. Try using .length instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code. Firstly `length` is a property, not a method, so you don't need the `()` suffix to invoke it. Secondly, there's no `className` attribute in HTML. This should just be `class`. Lastly the parent container shares the same class as the elements you're hiding, so all the child elements get hidden, even if they have `display: block` applied to them.

With these issues corrected, your code would look like this:

```js
function showPanel(id) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showPanel('p1')">test1</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('p2')">test2</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('p3')">test3</button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="p1" class="panel">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="p2" class="panel">
    <p class="other">TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="p3" class="panel">
    <p class="other">TEST3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it's worth noting that using `onX` attributes is outdated and not good practice. A better solution would be to use unobtrusive event handlers and provide custom metadata to the event handler through `data` attributes placed on the elements.

The improved version of the logic would look like this:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    panels.forEach(panel => {
      panel.style.display = panel.id === e.target.dataset.panel ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
  }); 
});
```

```html
<button data-panel="1">test1</button>
<button data-panel="2">test2</button>
<button data-panel="3">test3</button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="1" class="panel">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="panel">
    <p class="other">TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="panel">
    <p class="other">TEST3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for JS or Jquery. Instead of a button you can use an anchor tag. Then you calling with the anchor the id of the element. Last but not least you make the boxes hidden through CSS and use the `:target` selector to display the elements:

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">test1</a><br>
<a href="#2">test2</a><br>
<a href="#3">test3</a><br>

<div class="content-container">
  <div id="1" class="content">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="content">
    <p class="other">TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="content ">
    <p class="other">TEST3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution and probably the solution I would recommend, as long as you don’t have other elements on your page you will be targeting, which would cause a conflict with using :target.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell thats why you should call an "unique" id or class that is limited to those elements before `:target` as this will prevent your mentioned issue.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I am simply saying that if there are any targeting links inside the content he wants to conditionally display, clicking those will have the side effect of closing these boxes. It's also possible he will n eed to use targeting elsewhere while always leaving one of these boxes displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues.

- Length can be calculated using `elements.length` and not `elements.length()`
- You have given same class name to both the parent and the child divs. So hiding all elements with class name `content` will hide your whole parents itself. So after updating `style.display = "block"` to the required target, it will not work. Because your parent is already `style.display = "none"`. So you should make a logic update there. So I changed the parent class name.

```js
function showPanel(id) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showPanel('1')">test1</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('2')">test2</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('3')">test3</button>

<div>
  <div id="1" class="content">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="content">
    <p class="other">TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="content ">
    <p class="other">TEST3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way I might approach a prob,problem like this would be to tie the panels and their triggers together using data-attributes. This way, you don't risk conflicts with other IDs that m ay be the same on the page (IDs should always be unique).

Before setting up my event listener, I would initialize an `openPanel` variable and set it to any panel that is already created with the `active` class name. Whenever we open a new panel, we will overwrite this variable vaklue, so we don't need to do a new `querySelctor` each time.

Then, in the CSS, rather than hiding all panels and then showing the one with the active class, we can write a single style that hides any panels without the active class using the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) negation selector.

This is how that would look (initializing this with panel #1 open by default, but you can simply remove the active class from it in the HTML if you don't want that):

```js
let openPanel = document.querySelector('[data-panel-id].active');

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target?.matches?.('[data-panel-target]')) {
    const id = e.target.dataset.panelTarget;
    if (id) {
      const panel = document.querySelector(`[data-panel-id="${id}"]`);
      if (panel) {
        openPanel?.classList.remove('active');
        panel.classList.add('active');
        openPanel = panel;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
[data-panel-id]:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button data-panel-target="1">test1</button>
<button data-panel-target="2">test2</button>
<button data-panel-target="3">test3</button>

<main>
  <div data-panel-id="1" class="active">
    <p>TEST #1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-panel-id="2">
    <p>TEST #2</p>
  </div>
  <div data-panel-id="3">
    <p>TEST #3</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already submitted a separate solution with my preferred recommendation, but I wanted to provide an answer to your question using the same approach you started with so as not to deviate from the code you already have in place.

The code you already had in place was actually fairly close to working already. The main issue I saw was that you were using `document.getElementById(i)` where you should actually have been using `elements[i]`. We can improve this further though, by replacing the for loop with a for..of loop, and determining inline whether the current element being evaluated is the one we want to show. If so, we use `'block'`, otherwise `'none'`.

After initializing our function, we can call it on one of our IDs within the JS to have one panel open by default. **It's also important that the parent of all these `.content` elements NOT contain the class name `content` as well, as that would conflict with your function. I have replaced that parent element with a simple `<main>…</main>` element.

Here is how I would achieve solving this using your existing approach:

```js
function showPanel(contentId) {
  const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('content'));
  for (const element of elements) {
    element.style.display = element.id === contentId ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
showPanel('1');
```

```html
<button onclick="showPanel('1')">test1</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('2')">test2</button>
<button onclick="showPanel('3')">test3</button>

<main>
  <div id="1" class="content">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="content">
    <p>TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="content ">
    <p>TEST3</p>
  </div>
</main>
```